# How to create instance of class File?

Tags: java, class, file-io, reflection, jfilechooser

I've taken a class file(say `Foo.class`) using JFileChooser and stored it in a File class object(say `File a`).
now I've to read metadata like methods and variables of this `Foo.class` using reflection APIs.
My question is that, I've stored it in `a`, which is just a `File reference variable`. So how can I use any API on a File.
or any other suggestion for doing so are also welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

as i understand,first of all you need to convert class file to Class object you can do that via UrlClassLoader
Lets Assume you have File classFile and String className ( also you can figure it out className exactly same with filename)

```
 try {
    URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader( new URL[]{parent_directory});
    Class<?> clazz = classLoader.loadClass(className);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // something went wrong..
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

then now you have Class Object and you can use reflection to create Class Object

```
 try {
    Object instance = clazz.newInstance(); // if there no default constructor you need to get constructors list and create a object
    Method method = clazz.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, String.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(instance, argument);
} catch (Exception e) {
    // something went wrong..
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note that method name  is unknown you need to create a way to identifying.

Comment: The `URL` you pass to the `URLClassLoader` must represent the base directory rather than the class file. So you have to use the class’ parent directory or one of its ancestors, depending on the package of the selected class.

Comment: yeah thats true according to your comment answer was updated

Comment: yeah..but `loadClass` method takes binary name of a class as argument and in my File Class object, I only have absolute path of that class. Is there any solution for it? @mithatkonuk